# SQL ERROR: near "m": syntax error. In Statement: insert into table?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, xcode6

This is the method that I enter data in database table

Code:

```
- (void)AddNotes:(NSString *)notesDate andNoteText:(NSString *)notesText{

    NSString *insertData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into notes(notes_date_time,notes_text) Values('%@','%@')",notesDate,notesText];

    [self InsUpdateDelData:insertData];
}
```

Comment: There is no such error in that code.  It must be elsewhere.  There is a potential SQL-injection attack, however.

Comment: SQL-injection attack ???? @Droppy

Comment: Yeah using `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` to create SQL statements in inherently insecure.  You need to use bind variables.  Google for "sql injection attack" for the full story.

Comment: no duplication there but it give me random error some time its work properly but some time the data not saved into the database table of sqlite  @CL

Comment: This is an exact duplicate. (The problem is that your note contains a quote.)